# Custom Approval Workflow and Credentials

Tags: workflow, credentials, approval

We have developed several custom SharePoint workflows which are the same ones I have implemented in the past with no problem.  We are an intranet site and the users are already directly logged in.

I have a custom approval workflow that is prompting certain users for credentials when trying to close the task from outlook.  Some users have no problem closing the task.  No users get the credentials prompt when closing a custom collect feedback.

**Could this be a User Profile Synchronization condition?**

After researching I have already tried the following on the users computers with no resolution:

- Internet Options Enable Protected Mode no selected.
- Require Server Verification not checked
- Automatic logon only in Intranet Zone checked
- Outlook always prompt for logon credentialss unchecked
- Encrypt back to server unchecked
- COM Add-Ins disabled both SharePoint and Social Connector
- In trusted site
- Added generic credential

Appreciate any assistance on this please!